# MySQL FORCE INDEX location in JOINed query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm having a little trouble getting MySQL to put an INDEX() on the right fields. I have a query that would look, for example, something like this:

```
SELECT m.id as mid,p.id as pid,po.* FROM m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN p ON p.mid = m.id AND p.uid = 2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN po ON po.mid = m.id AND po.uid = 2 
ORDER BY m.date,m.time
```

And I have the following indexes:

- m.date
- m.time
- p.mid
- p.uid
- po.mid
- po.uid

However, when I run an `EXPLAIN` query, none of the keys are being picked up. I tried to put `FORCE INDEX` statements in, but MySQL keeps rejecting them (saying there is a syntax error in the query). Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here's the `EXPLAIN`:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  m   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    31  Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  p   ref mid,uid mid 5   db.m.id 1   
1   SIMPLE  po  ref uid,mid uid 5   const   1
```

Note that p and po are being handle fine now, but m still isn't. I just added an INDEX(date, time) for m, and still got the same.

Comment: It seems you only have 31 rows in the table. What is the problem with how MySQL is executing the query? Whatever the EXPLAIN plan is, it should be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FORCE INDEX is usually used after the table name, i.e.

```
... FROM <table_name> FORCE INDEX (<index_name>)
```

But I don't recommend using it. If you'd like it to be ordered using index, you may create compound index IDX_date_time on (m.`date`, m.`time`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have such indexes:

1. `(p.mid, p.uid)` - compound one
2. `(po.mid, po.uid)` - another compound one
3. `(m.date, m.time)` - another compound one

PS: how much (in percentage) of rows from each of the tables is being selected with this query? If the value is big (more than 30%) - then mysql doesn't use indexes intentionally

Comment: So if I would do ALTER TABLE p ADD INDEX(mid,uid), it would pick it up automatically?

Comment: Percentages: m is all rows, po and p only a couple.

Comment: @Dow: it depends on a lot of things, but the set of indexes I mentioned in answer is a recommended set for such query

Comment: Ok, and suppose MySQL doesn't accept them but I want to FORCE it anyway, how would I do that, in the overall query?

Comment: @Dow: forcing index is a bad practice. If mysql doesn't use index - there is a **valid** reason to do so. Please post `EXPLAIN`

Comment: @Dow: uhm, I see that for `p` and `po` indexes **are** used

Comment: Zerkms: correct, but (date,time) is not, even after I have added the index.

Comment: @Dow: it is ordering. It is tricky thing to optimize order. For example - in this particular case you need to read `m.id`, while sort by another columns. This could be an issue.